# NHibernate 3 full-text searching with table-per-subclass setup

Tags: nhibernate, full-text-search

I'm using FluentNHibernate and I have just moved to NHibernate 3.0. I have also changed my database schema to a table-per-subclass configuration which I really like. We used full-text search before using MS SQL 2005's built in full-text search which worked fine because all of our content was of one class and one table. Now that our data is spread out among different subclasses/tables with different fields to be indexed on each class we will typically want one search against all subclasses. What is the best way to accomplish this and how would I query it?

We have been using Linq more lately but I would be OK with HQL.

Comment: Is this question hard to understand. Do I need code examples that demonstrate what I wish I could do?

Comment: I am a Junior so doubt i could help but I would be interested in seeing a good example of your mapping, I have not come across this table-per-subclass configuration pattern that you speak of before.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by chaining by HQL queries like this...

```
string selectCat = @"from Cat c where freetext((c.Name),:keyword)";
string selectDog = @"from Dog d where freetext((d.Name,d.OwnerName),:keyword)";

var animals = session.CreateQuery(selectCat).SetString("keyword", keyword).List<BaseAnimal>().Concat<BaseAnimal>(session.CreateQuery(selectDog).SetString("keyword", keyword).List<BaseAnimal>()).ToList<BaseAnimal();
```